# Unwanted newline characters in JSON while web scraping

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to extract info from this [website](https://www.petlebi.com/) using Scrapy. But the info I need is in a JSON file; and this JSON file has unwanted literal newlines characters in only the description section.

Here is an [example page](https://www.petlebi.com/kemirgen-urunleri/karlie-seramik-hamster-ve-guinea-pig-mama-kabi-100ml-8cm.html) and the JSON element I want to scrape is this

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Product",
            "description": "Hamster ve Guinea Pig için tasarlanmış temizliği kolay mama kabıdır.

Hamster motifleriyle süslü ve son derece sevimlidir.

Ürün seramikten yapılmıştır 

Ürün ölçüleri 


    Hacim: 100 ml
    Çap: 8 cm",
      "name": "Karlie Seramik Hamster ve Guinea Pigler İçin Yemlik 100ml 8cm",
      "image": "https://www.petlebi.com/up/ecommerce/product/lg_karlie-hamster-mama-kaplari-359657192.jpg",
      "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Karlie"
      },
      "category": "Guinea Pig Yemlikleri",
      "sku": "4016598440834",
      "gtin13": "4016598440834",
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
         "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
         "price": "149.00",
        "priceCurrency": "TRY",
        "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
        "url": "https://www.petlebi.com/kemirgen-urunleri/karlie-seramik-hamster-ve-guinea-pig-mama-kabi-100ml-8cm.html"
      },
      "review": [
            ]
    }
    </script>
```

As you can see there are literal newline characters in the description, which are not allowed in JSON. Here is the code I was trying but it didn't work:

```
import scrapy
import json
import re

class JsonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'json_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.petlebi.com/kemirgen-urunleri/karlie-seramik-hamster-ve-guinea-pig-mama-kabi-100ml-8cm.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract the script content containing the JSON data
        script_content = response.xpath('/html/body/script[12]').get()

        if not script_content:
            self.logger.warning("Script content not found.")
            return

        json_data_match = re.search(r'<script type="application/ld\+json">(.*?)<\/script>', script_content, re.DOTALL)
        if json_data_match:
            json_data_str = json_data_match.group(1)
            try:
                json_obj = json.loads(json_data_str)

                product_info = {
                    "name": json_obj.get("name"),
                    "description": json_obj.get("description"),
                    "image": json_obj.get("image"),
                    "brand": json_obj.get("brand", {}).get("name"),
                    "category": json_obj.get("category"),
                    "sku": json_obj.get("sku"),
                    "price": json_obj.get("offers", {}).get("price"),
                    "url": json_obj.get("offers", {}).get("url")
                }

                self.logger.info("Extracted Product Information: %s", product_info)

                with open('product_info.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
                    json.dump(product_info, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                self.logger.error("Error decoding JSON: %s", e)

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.petlebi.com/kemirgen-urunleri/karlie-seramik-hamster-ve-guinea-pig-mama-kabi-100ml-8cm.html',
            callback=self.parse,
        )
```

I want this to be a dynamic code so it works for every product.

I used https://jsonlint.com/ to see the unwanted characters and when i delete the escape characters in the description it says it is valid. I tried `html.unescape` but it didn't work. The code stops working in this line:
`json_obj = json.loads(json_data_str)` How can I do it?

Comment: I can see no escape characters. Some of the strings contain literal newlines which _should_ be escaped.

Comment: I have changed the picture but i think people should still see the whole json for my code to make sense. What do you say?

Comment: You still haven't clarified what the problem is. You say there are escape characters but there are none. Please [edit] again to spell out what exactly you think is problematic. If the site serves you invalid JSON then you can either complain to them or try to work around the problem. `string.replace("\n", "\\n")` would turn a `string` containing the problematic JSON into valid JSON I believe.

Comment: Sigh. I went ahead and edited the question. If that's not what you meant, probably (delete this and) ask a new question with more details to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Thank you for the help. My first language isn't English so I couldn't grasp what were you asking. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing newlines only within the `"description":` value is a little bit more involved than I'd like, but try this.

```
                json_data_str_fixed = re.sub(
                    r'"description": "[^"]*(\n[^"]*)*"',
                    lambda x: re.sub(r"\n", r"\\n", x.group(0)),
                    json_data_str)
                json_obj = json.loads(json_data_str_fixed)
```

In so many words, the outer `re.sub` selects the `"desription":` key *and value*, including any newlines, and replaces it with ... the same string with the newlines replaced with escaped newlines by the inner `re.sub`.

If you don't want to preserve the newlines at all, of course, this is much simpler; just

```
                json_obj = json.loads(json_data_str.replace("\n", "")
```

but understand that this will turn e.g. `yapılmıştır`(newline)(newline)`Ürün` into `yapılmıştırÜrün` which probably isn't what you want.

Using `json.loads(..., strict=False)` as suggested in the other answer is probably easier in your scenario; but I wanted to provide an answer which can be adapted to scenarios where this doesn't work. (I would upvote, and suggest you accept, the other answer if it didn't suggest munging the text as its primary solution.)

Demo: https://ideone.com/okXYok

Comment: I don't need to preserve new lines but this didn't work. I have printed out the new json_data_str. It doesn't seem to be changed.

Comment: @esyilmaz Perhaps you misunderstood how to use it. I have added a demo link now.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the specific `char` from the `response` text before converted into `json object` like this

```
json_data_str.replace("\n","").replace("\r","").replace("\t","")
```

Or you can specify the parameter `strict` on `json.loads` function

```
json.loads(json_data_str,strict=False)
```

Comment: The first approach will turn e.g. `yapılmıştır`(newline)(newline)`Ürün` into `yapılmıştırÜrün` which is probably undesired. The second is fine.